# What is the current flow logic of this NPN configuration

Tags: npn, saturation

For a switch i need to put the transistor in cutoff to OFF and saturated for ON as shown in the lecture bellow.
My input is a voltage source i need to control the base current to make the collector current as high as possible ,saturated state.
How do i control the current going into the the base .

how can i see the current mechanism of the circuit bellow?
Thanks.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Wasn't this posted yesterday?

Answer (score 0):

The base current is approximately:

**Ib = (Vcc - 0.7) / (Rb + Beta * RL)**

In order to reach maximum collector current the Rb should be zero. This circuit is safety working with zero ohm Rb. But even with Rb=0 ohm you never reache saturated state of trasistor, there always will be some Vce drop (at least 0.7v).

[image]

Answer (score -1):

An emitter-follower biased (your R8) from its collector power supply voltage will never be saturated. As its base and emitter voltages rise then the base current decreases until a situation occurs where there is not enough base current for any more emitter current.

Comment: my question is how do i know what is the base current in general in such structure?

Comment: The purpose of the question is to bias it via the red arrowed connection and override R8.